# How to make 3d model of small geographical area?

Tags: android, ios, 3d, maps

I wasn't sure how exactly to title this question, but what I want to do is make 3d model of small geographical area. The user has to be able to drag point of view, and interact with objects. (detecting touch on objects in that 3d world)
What tools/sdk should I use to achieve this for iOS and Android? 
any direction is welcome.